# browser in quirks mode

Tags: html, css, browser

My browser always run in quirks mode - is it a problem?

I can't even validate my css. My page is looking good .. is there any problem?

Thanks a tonne in advance  :)

Comment: Your *browser* doesn't always run in quirks mode; some *pages* may. Please clarify what you are talking about.

Comment: Which browser, and how do I activate "quirks" mode?

Comment: @pekka no my website contains three pages  n all three are in quirks mode

Comment: @Paul it's alignment is perfect

Comment: @FrustatedWithFormsDesigner it shows ModeNavigator:IE8 ModeDocument:Quirks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you set a valid doctype in your header.
ex:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

if you do not have that you will always be in quirks mode.

Comment: it works with this .. but my page moved a bit  to left :(

Comment: Now its time for you to look into reset css files. Thats the secret to control of your layout accross browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Standards are meant as a contract between browser vendors and the web designers. You are violating this contract. While this may work now, you are not guaranteed that it will work tomorrow.